# How to convert m/d/y into d/m/y in DB?

Tags: laravel-5

My date is save in db as 08/07/1990. I want to display it in web as 08 july 1990

When I use this format `date('d-F-Y',strtotime($date));`

It display as 07 Aug 1990 instead of 08 july 1990.

Answer (score -2):

Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed. Check more here: [php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php](https://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
$dateInput = '08/07/1990';
$date      = str_replace('/', '-', $dateInput);
echo date('d-F-Y', strtotime($date));
```

//08-July-1990

Upvote if found your answer. *but one thing is clear that if you saved year as 1990 then it can't possible to make it 2019.

Comment: what....... this is 100% false

Comment: i tried it and working very well here. try again it is working code

Comment: I'm not on about the code, I'm on about your whole first paragraph

Comment: means code solved your problem? if then why downvote.

Comment: because the explanation is incorrect. You can create a date from a format - there is no date assumption. Date requires a date to be in YYYY-MM-DD format

Comment: its not working